# How to set dynamically Enabled='<%=Exceeds2dCatalogCount()?false:true%>' in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to set properties `Enabled='<%=Exceeds2dCatalogCount()?false:true%>'` to my asp.net button. but It gives me an error

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string
>   representation '<%=Exceeds2dCatalogCount()?false:true%>' for the
>   'Enabled' property.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: why not to return a boolean value from the Exceeds2dCatalogCount() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `<%# %>` (Binding expression) and invoke `DataBind()` to write value at property. Depends upon the return datatype of your page method `Exceeds2dCatalogCount()` you may write following code.

`Enabled='<%# Exceeds2dCatalogCount() ? false : true %>'`  //<---If return type is boolean.

`Enabled='<%# (Exceeds2dCatalogCount()==1 ? false : true) %>'`

Invoke the `YourControlID.DataBind()` method in page_load event.